# Windows explorer hangs up FTP connection after PASV command

Tags: windows, ftp, explorer

I try to implement a simple FTP server. It works with total commander and firefoxm but windows explorer works very strange. It sends 'PASV' command, gets the answer with IP and PORT numbers and then just throws an error ('cound not connect server' or something similar, no description). I can't understand why does it do so.

Or maybe I can force explorer to use active mode somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. My server was opening passive port only after getting command, and explorer was waiting for it to be ready just after PASV.